# Install godaddy certificate on Google cloud Ingress

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, godaddy-api

We are working on installing the GoDaddy certificate on to Google Cloud. GoDaddy has provided the 3 files, one ###.crt file bundle.crt file and a pem file. We also have a ingress rule configured in our GKE. We are looking for a solution how to apply these certificates.

Comment: 1) Create a TLS secret. 2) Apply the secret to Ingress. 3) This guide should help you get started: https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-secure-applications-on-kubernetes-ssl-tls-certificates-8f7f5751d788

Comment: @JohnHanley., The solution you provided works for the single certificate. In case of godaddy it provided two .crt files. If we apply only one the ssl doesnt work. So we were exploring the way how to use those certificates.

Comment: Combine both certificates together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution solved the issue.

```
cat xxxx.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > chain.crt
kubectl create secret tls --cert chain.crt --key xxxx.key <secret_name>
```